# Socket: Client was disconnected or not?

Tags: windows, linux, sockets

I am creating socket server. But I do not know, How I can know client disconnected or not?
I am creating server under Windows and using berkeley sockets function (read, send, connect....).
Preferably I want a cross-platfomennoe solution (without WSA functions).

I can write to socket 0 byte and ckeck error. But it is not good solution.

Comment: Read can hangs if client is not disconnected and socket has not data.
Or Maybe I am wrong. 
Or I must use nonblock sockets?

Comment: @unick The assumption is you'll be reading in a loop anyway, for the normal read case.

Answer (score 4):

When a client disconnects, you'll get a "read" event but the read() will return 0.

```
ssize_t bytes_read;
if ((bytes_read = read(...)) == 0)
{
    // client disconnected
}
else if (bytes_read == -1)
{
    // some sort of error (also no data available when using non-blocking sockets).
}
else
{
    // you have bytes_reads bytes to process
}
```

Comment: You're right to point out EAGAIN, but there's also EINTR, which means your process got a signal while reading.  I usually handle both of these.

Comment: Also he mentioned he's using Windows, so he needs to use recv() instead of read().